# Using custom Swing classes in FXML

Tags: java, swing, javafx, fxml

Following a former StackOverflow suggestion, I extended the `DefaultStyledDocument` Swing class in order to support custom text with syntax hilight. Is there a way to make FXML support my class extending `DefaultStyledDocument`? Or better, does JavaFX has a component equivalent to `DefaultStyledDocument`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a `SwingNode` to embed your swing classes in a javafx application. Details about how to use this class can be found in an oracle tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm).